x86 opcodes for the xor instruction, cannot find detail required in manuals
Some instructions with corresponding opcodes:
xor eax, eax     \x31\xc0
xor ecx, ecx     \x31\xc9
xor edx, edx     \x31\xd2 
xor ebx, ebx     \x31\xdb

Could someone please explain the calculation behind the second byte (it increases in steps of 9 down the list) and the reason for the \xc0 'base'?

FYI, this information is in the Intel Software Developer's Manual, Volume 2, Chapter 2, sections 2.1.3, 2.1.5, and table 2-2.

https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#ModR/M_and_SIB_bytes

The two most significant bits (6 and 7) of this byte correspond to the MOD field. When they both are 1, the register addressing mode is enabled, and other 6 bits determine two registers (3 bits per one register):

000 - EAX
001 - ECX
010 - EDX
011 - EBX
100 - ESP
101 - EBP
110 - ESI
111 - EDI


.......giving 1<<3 + 1 = 9 . Thank you Stas, much appreciated.
